# How do I find all of the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of this?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If P be the vector space of all polynomials, and define the linear transformation $T : P → P$ by $T f(x)  = xf′(x).$ How do I find all eigenvalues and eigenvectors of T.

I'm not sure how to do this problem since it does not give a specific matrix and just lists it's as "all polynomials."

Comment: If $Tf = \lambda f$ then $f=\ ?$

Comment: The eigenvectors in this case are some familiar polynomials.

Answer (score 3):

If $f$ is (non-zero) constant then it is clearly an eigenvector to eigenvalue $0$. In fact, every monomial $cx^n$ is eigenvector for eigenvalue $n$. And if we work in characteristic zero, these are all eigenvectors: If  $f(x)=a_nx^n+\cdots+a_1x+a_0$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda$ and there are at least two non-zero coefficients $a_j,a_n$, then we find that both $\lambda=n$ and $\lambda=j$, contradiction.

Answer (score 3):

Another way. Let $y=f(x)$ a polynomial, we want:
$$
xy'=\lambda y
$$
this is a differential equation that can be solved by separation of variables as:
$$
\frac{dy}{y}=\lambda \frac{dx}{x} \rightarrow y=kx^\lambda
$$
and, since it must be a polynomial $\lambda$ must be an integer.

Comment: Very nice approach. +1

Answer (score 2):

A number $\;\lambda\;$ is an eigenvalue of $\;T\;$ iff there exists

$$0\neq p(x)=\sum_{k=0}^na_kx^k\in P\;,\; xp'(x)=\lambda p(x)\iff$$

$$\sum_{k=0}^n\lambda a_kx^k= x\sum_{k=1}^nka_kx^{k-1}=\sum_{k=1}^n ka_kx^k$$

Comparing coefficients of same exponents of $\;x\;$ , we have that

$$a_0=0\;,\;\;\lambda a_k=ka_k\iff\begin{cases}a_k=0\\\text{or}\\\lambda =k\,,\,\;\text{if}\;a_k\neq0\end{cases}$$

Thus, there cannot be two different nonzero coefficients in $\;p(x)\;$ , so an eigenvector looks like
$$\;p(x)=ax^n\;,\;\;n\ge 0\;,\;\;a\neq 0\implies Tp(x)=nax^n=np(x)\;,\;\;\lambda=n$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

In the canonical basis $1,x,x^2,x^3,\cdots$, the matrix is

$$\left(\begin{matrix}
&0 &0 &0 &0 &\cdots\\
&0 &1 &0 &0 &\cdots\\
&0 &0 &2 &0 &\cdots\\
&0 &0 &0 &3 &\cdots\\
&&&\cdots
\end{matrix}\right).$$

The eigenvalues are obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x) = \sum_{i=0}^n a_ix^i$ be an eigenvector of $T$ for the eigenvalue $\lambda$. Then we have
$$
\sum_{i=0}^n\lambda a_ix^i = \lambda f(x) = (Tf)(x) = xf'(x) = \sum_{i=0}^n a_iix^i,
$$
i. e. $\lambda a_i = a_ii$ for all $i=0,\dotsc,n$. If $a_i\neq 0$ for some $i$, then it follows that $\lambda = i$. Hence we have $\lambda = i\in \mathbb N$ is the eigenvalue and $f(x) = x^i$ is an eigenvector.